# Confused by Javascript's variable scope

Tags: javascript

I'm finding myself by Javascript's variable scope, could someone explain to me why the first example doesn't work but the second does?

```
function test() {
  return typeof(the_variable) !== 'undefined' && the_variable;
}

(function () {
   var the_variable = "doesn't work";
   console.log(test());
}());

var the_variable = "does work";
console.log(test());
```

Output I get in my log:

```
false
does work
```

Also I would like to know how to do something similar to the first example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explained in comments:

```
function test() {
  return typeof(the_variable) !== 'undefined' && the_variable;
}

// The variable in this function is scoped to the anonymous function.
// It doesn't exist outside that function, so `test` cannot see it
(function () {
   var the_variable = "doesn't work";
   console.log(test());
}());

// This variable exists in a scope that wraps the `test` function, so it can see it.
var the_variable = "does work";
console.log(test());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions define scope. In your first example `the_variable` is outside of the scope of `test`. On the other hand, in the second example, `the_variable` is defined in the global scope and is available everywhere.

EDIT

Catch `the_variable` in a closure if you want it to be available to `test`.

```
var foo = (function () {
   var the_variable = "does work";
   function test() {
       return typeof(the_variable) !== 'undefined' && the_variable;
   }
   return {test : test};
}()); 
console.log(foo.test());
```

Output:

does work

Comment: `function test()` opens a new scope. `var` from the enclosing anonymous function will not be available. Catch `the_variable` in a closure if it to be available.