# Behavior of scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confused by Javascript's variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399799/confused-by-javascripts-variable-scope)

For example, this is my JavaScript code:

```
var foo = 'Originalvalue';
var foo = 'Nextvalue';
alert(foo); // Nextvalue
```

So then, now I am sure writing `var` in front of an already-declared variable just simply is nullified and of no use to the program.

But then consider this program:

```
var foo = 'Originalvalue';
function duhfoo() {
  var foo = 'Newbievalue';
}
duhfoo();
alert(foo); // Originalvalue
```

Then, from the logic explained in my first example, the value should be 'Originalvalue', as there is already a variable called `foo`. Then why is it like so?

Comment: it's called lexical scoping if you want to look it up further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript there are two kinds of variables: **local** variables and **global** variables.

When using `var` outside of functions you are declaring a **global** variable and the same happens if you don't use `var` at all. Writing

```
foo = "first";
```

at top level (outside any function) is the same as `var foo = "first"`.

When inside a function however things are different, and the keyword `var` discriminates between **local** and **global** variables:

```
var foo = "first";
var bar = "second";

function f()
{
    var foo = "third"; // local
    bar = "fourth";    // global
}

f();
alert([foo, bar]); // output will be first,fourth
```

In other words when you use `var` inside a function the variable will be a different one with the same name, visible only by code written inside the boundaries of the function.

Please note that the boundary is determined by the function, and not the braces `{...}`. If you have nested blocks and use another `var` declaration inside the blocks the variable will be the same and this is different from what happens in other languages like Java, C or C++.

The only way to create a *scope* is to define a function (including a function inside a function).

Another very important thing to remember in Javascript (especially if having been exposed to similar-looking languages in which this concept is not present like Java, C or C++) is the idea of "capture"/"closure"...

```
var foo = "first";

function f()
{
    // Local variable
    var foo = "second";

    function g()
    {
        // This is the local foo of f, not the global
        // one even if there is no "var" declaration
        // inside this nested scope
        return foo;
    }

    return g;
}

var nested_function = f();

alert([foo, nested_function()]); // output will be first,second
```

Basically a local variable can "outlive" the function that defined it, by being used by other functions that are said to "capture" that variable. A function that captures one or more variable is called "closure".

In other words a local variable is only **visible** inside the body of the function, but it may live longer than then function like it happens for the local `foo` of last example in which the variable survived after returning from `f` because it has been captured by closure `g`.

Answer (score 2):

well variable foo inside duhfoo clearly states that its scope is duhfoo() method and not global.

Answer (score 2):

Because

(From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet))

> **var** has the following properties
>
> - function-scoped
> - hoist to the top of its function
> - redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are no-ops

Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) for more information on this subject.

Comment: mark-robson, it means redecleration has no effect